# Reading The Last Parts Of An Arraylist :Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to read the last 8 parts of an arraylist. But I am having a bit of trouble. This is my code so far:

```
for(int j2 = 0; j2 < chatList.size() && j2 < 8; j2++)
    {
        if(chatEnabled) GameMain.CourierFont(this,""+chatList.get(j2), cWindowX + 4, cWindowY - (16 + -j2 * 10));
    }
```

Can somebody help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: you have got 8 answers below. if it has solved your problem.Why don't you accept any of the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop:

```
 for(int j2 = chatList.size() - 8; j2 < chatList.size(); j2++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) may be convenient:

```
List<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<Chat>();
// initialize
int last = chatList.size();
int first = last - Math.min(8, chatList.size());
List<Chat> recent = chatList.subList(first, last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the last 8 parts of your `ArrayList`, your `for` loop reads the *first* 8.

What you instead want to do is start at the size-8th element and then loop until the last element, therefore your code should look something like:

```
int size = chatList.size();
int start = (size > 8) ? size - 8 : 0;

for(int j2 = start; j2 < size; j2++) {
   ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Forgot about the case where `size` might be less than 8. If that's the case then you should start at element 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int j2 = chatList.size() - 8;
while(j2 < chatList.size() && (chatList.size() - 8) >= 0) {
    if(chatEnabled) GameMain.CourierFont(this,""+chatList.get(j2), cWindowX + 4, cWindowY - (16 + -j2 * 10));
}
```

i think you should check whether your chatList's size more than 8

Answer (score 0):

```
int chatListSize = chatList.size();

// if you do not do this check,the code will fail miserably.
if ( chatListSize > 8) {

for(int i = chatListSize - 8; i < chatListSize; i++) {    

            //TO-DO
     } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition **j2 < chatList.size() && j2 < 8** will check whether j2 is smaller than the list size and 8, means the loop will iterate from **index 0 to 7**, it will not read last 8 elements instead it reads first 8 elements.

Instead you can give your condition as

```
j2<chatList.size() && j2>=chatList.size()-8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List l1 = new ArrayList();       
    int size=l1.size();
    int i;
    for(i=size-8;i<size;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(l1.get(i));
    }
    }
```

I think this is the simple way of doing it .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following loop:

```
int size = charList.size() > 7 ? charList.size() - 8 : 0;
for(int j2 = size; j2< charList.size();j2++)
```